# Why is this class visible by this templated class?

Tags: c++, templates

I didn't expect this to compile but it does. I'm wondering if this is guaranteed to happen or whether it's just compiler-specific. I'm wondering why 'OSInterface::handleOSEvents()' can see the 'InputHandler' class and its member function. If OSInterface is an ordinary class then it doesn't compile, the order of the class definitions must be swapped.

```
template <typename input_handler_t>
class OSInterface
{
public:
    void readOSEvents()
    {
        input_handler_t::handleKeyDown(5);
    }
};


struct InputHandler
{
    static void handleKeyDown(int a) {};
};


int main()
{
   
   OSInterface<InputHandler> os;
    os.readOSEvents();
    
}
```

Edit: I was thinking the compiler must be doing something special with it, because if it instantiates the template class in the order that it's declared then it shouldn't be able to see 'InputHandler' and call its member function. On the other let's say that it instantiates the class right at the bottom of the .cpp then it would be able to see 'InputHandler' but I wouldn't be able to create an object of that class in main().

Comment: Templates are not instantiate until needed, which in this case happens in `main` where everything is visible.

Comment: @JHBonarius Oops, yeah, they're irrelevant, deleted

Comment: The same as @RichardCritten, this is the normal behaviour.  Take into account that OSInterface<InputHandler> in the bincode is a class itself. 
The time this templated-class is "created/defined" is on it's first usage: In your code, on the main function.
Just see the object/functions of your compiled code and demangle them to verify it.

Comment: @Ralequi So is that the equivalent to being defined in main() then? It's only needed in main so is it defined there?

Comment: @Zebrafish exactly, and at that point everything needed is previously loaded/known so it should work

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering why 'OSInterface::handleOSEvents()' can see the 'InputHandler' class and its member function.

There is no `OSInterface::handleOSEvents()` in the example. I assume that you mean `OSInterface::readOSEvents()`.

Because `OSInterface` is instantiated after `InputHandler` was defined.

> I'm wondering if this is guaranteed to happen or whether it's just compiler-specific.

The program is well-formed. The program will compile with all standard conforming language implementations.

Comment: Sorry, that Foo was there by accident. So this is guaranteed to compile then? thanks.

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes.